# Sorting an NSArray in ascending order with Ending zeros

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios6, xcode4.3, xcode4.5

I am sorting my distances Array using Sort Descriptor in ascending order but there are few indexes which doesn't hold distances so I am storing a greater number where distances are not found which help me sort my array properly. But storing a greater number where distances are not found is not a good approach. Therefore I am looking for a solution which sort my distances in ascending order where found and where it doesn't found so it should be sorted in ending indexes without hard coding a greater number in NSArray. My Code for sorting is as below.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.distanceArr);  // self.distanceArr is a Mutable Array
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"OnlyDistance" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sort = [self.distanceArr mutableCopy];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [sort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    NSLog(@"Sorted %@",sortedArray);
    NSLog(@"%d",[sortedArray count]);

    self.sortedBusinessDetArr = [sortedArray mutableCopy];


    [self.searchTbl reloadData];
```

And my Array is as follow

```
(
{
    OnlyDistance = "10000.0";  ///   Hard Coded Value where distance is not found.
},
    {
    OnlyDistance = "13089.53";
},
    {
    OnlyDistance = "12991.81";
}, 
{
    OnlyDistance = "10000.0";  ///   Hard Coded Value where distance is not found.
}, 
{
    OnlyDistance = "10000.0";  ///   Hard Coded Value where distance is not found.
},
    {
    OnlyDistance = "13089.53";
}
```

)

OnlyDistance is an NSNumber where float values are stored. And If I stored 0.0 is NSNumber so it is also sorting as
ascending with zeros on top. And I want value holding zeros or not found result to be sort as bottom and only index which holds values should be on top. I cant sort it in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

DO it like this

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
[self.distanceArr sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```